# Can I anchor two vertices together from two different meshes and have them move in tandem when creating poses?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I'm creating a character model for a Unity project. The character is composed of a few different parts separated into different meshes. I'm wondering if it's possible to effectively "join" two meshes together for the purpose of animating without actually joining them together.

Is there a way to say "I want vertex A from mesh A and vertex B from mesh B to be in the same position when being posed"?

Comment: Not an expert at rigging but as far as I know you can parent different objects to the same bone, so when it moves both move along with it. You can also use hooks, but that is probably a Blender specific feature, and wont be exported to other software

Comment: Please clarify, perhaps with pictures, exactly what you mean by meshes. It is a common error among novice users of Blender to confuse the meaning of "meshes" and "objects" .When you write that you want to join different parts of the character separated into separate meshes, are the two meshes part of the same Blender object, or different ones?